# Crontab java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with a jar file

Tags: java, sqlite, shell, jar, cron

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk
 CLASSPATH=/Users/sunny/CronTest/out/production/CronTest 
 $JAVA_HOME/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH ".:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar" sample.Main 
 exit 0
```

Sqlite jar file is in `/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar`

Compiled java class file is in `/Users/sunny/CronTest/out/production/CronTest/sample/Main.class`

And I've set the cron job to be schedule at every 1 minute. Java class is getting exucuted but I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`

Same command which is in script is working in terminal.

My question is how can I add jar file properly to be executed from shell script.

Comment: try combining both classpaths into a single one and then pass it to java

Comment: Looks like you are missing a ":" after $CLASSPATH. Should be `$CLASSPATH:".:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar"`

Comment: Hi @Frank and Sanjeev I tried both the ways but still not working.

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I have no Unix-system to try. What if you build the complete classpath  in line 3? `CLASSPATH=/Users/sunny/CronTest/out/production/CronTest:.:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar` and then use only `-cp $CLASSPATH` in your call?

Comment: Not working in shell script. But working perfectly in terminal from root.

Comment: Hi @Frank. I got it working. Actually whenever I was opening the `cron.sh` file for editing, the system was generating copy of the that file with the name `cron copy.sh`. And I was running ./cron.sh like an idiot. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a space in between your `$CLASS PATH` and `".:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar"` and missing a colon(:).

Please try with following with `export`:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/Users/sunny/CronTest/out/production/CronTest:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar
```

and call java command with `-cp $CLASSPATH`.

If it still not work, please try with `-cp` directly:

```
$JAVA_HOME/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp ".:/Users/sunny/CronTest/out/production/CronTest:/Users/sunny/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar" sample.Main
```